# Responsive Web template doesn't run in diffrent screen sizes

Tags: php, html, httpresponse, response.redirect

I'm trying run Voyage a Flat Travel Responsive Web (`https://w3layouts.com/voyage-flat-travel-responsive-web-template/`) in 00webhosting and you can you can check the source in bitbucket (`https://bitbucket.org/nuwan300/trip/src`). When run this in web browser or mobile I will come to home screen but it won't navigate to other screens and it gives following error `http://error404.000webhost.com/?` (web site url is `http://travia.site11.com/`)

This app has three php files `config.php`, `detect.php`. Those two php files are inside the app folder and `index.php` file runs first time.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuwan if you take a closer look at the w3layouts links structure for voyage theme you would see this :

Destination page : https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/voyage/web/destinations.html
Cruises page : https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/voyage/web/criuses.html

On your implementation of the theme for whatever reason you have this :

Destination page : http://travia.site11.com/destinations.html
Criuses page : http://travia.site11.com/web/criuses.html

So already you miss an important element of the link - the **web** folder. If you add **web** to your links you'll see the real page not the 404 page.  
**http://travia.site11.com/web/destinations.html**

Please tell me if that helped

Comment: i tried that and change as you mention but css and images not loading as expected, url of css and javascrip pointed as you mention web/./..

Comment: I confirm that the css files, images and other dependencies doesn't work ... And that can be caused by various reasons . At least on your server do you see the css/images/js folders?  
Where are them located ?

Comment: no i can't see any css/images/js folders and those folder located in side the web folder can i know the solution for this issue ?

Comment: Before looking forward of a solution I would like to say to you that this site is created upon two important concepts : share and respect of eachother. 
I took the time to analyse your problem and normally would be that you show some respect to all participants of your post with upvotes if they deserve it. This way you assure more responses and a quicker solution to your problem

Comment: Nuwan ... do you have an .htaccess file ?